# How to test functions within Javascriptcore?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, chai, javascriptcore

I have seen many examples where someone takes a JavaScript function and evaluates it by doing something like:

```cc
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init]];
    [context evaluateScript:@"var add = function(a, b) {return a + b;}"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [context[@"add"] callWithArguments:@[@20, @30]]); //Output is 50
```

But how can we run test cases on the function? By calling arguments we can see the result (assuming it doesn't throw an exception). In the event it does throw an exception we can set an exception handler on the context prior to calling the code.

But what is the best way for testing code, using something like `Mocha` or `Chai` within `JavaScriptCore`?

Comment: I don't know objective-c, so i cannot write example, but i found this: https://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/#showing-off-with-mustache. I'm guessing, you could pass mocha.js to `evaluateScript`, then pass your test files there too. Once it works, you could write simple, reusable wrapper function that would setup and init tests on existing `JSContext`.

Comment: Since mocha may need some APIs that JavaScriptCore does not support, you may need to either emulate them or use different test runner/framework. There's https://github.com/WebReflection/wru that claims to support JSC, but it looks like it is an abandoned project.

Comment: What apis does mocha need?

Comment: Have you tried "loading" Mocha to `JSContext`? Mocha was written for Node.js and browsers, so it's possible that it depends on some stuff, that JavaScriptCore does not provide by default. I found this: https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-successfully-setup-a-unit-testing-for-React-Native-using-mocha but it's from 2015 so it may be outdated.

Comment: Nope I haven’t. I’m pretty clueless on how to start - I tried working with a port of node.js for javascriptcore which I couldn’t get to work, so I thought I should just ask someone.

Comment: I would try something similar to the article i linked first, but simplified as much as possible: write "testrunner.js" file with a simple `function runTest (fn) {try {fn()} catch (err) {console.error(err);}}`. Then another file, "mytest.js", with something like: `runTest(function testAdd () {console.assert(add(20, 30) === 50, 'Adding 20 and 30 should return 50')})`. After that, i would try to evaluate three scripts in the same `JSContext`: first your script with `add` function defined, then `testrunner.js` and finally `mytest.js`. If all would work ok, i would try using test framework lib.

Comment: Later you cold try to, for example, use `rollup` to "compile" a single JavaScript file and evaluate only that file contents. That's assuming you want to write tests in JavaScript, and not in objective-c (in which case using JS test framework/library wouldn't be that useful). Also, if you want to define JS function in objective-c, like you did in your example, just replace "first your script with add function defined" i wrote above with "first your code with add function defined". So, to summarize: i would try to do what a browser/node.js would do: load all code and run it :).

Comment: ok, I will try those things. But I think if someone who actually has experience does a proper write up it would be of a lot of benefit to many people.

Comment: I agree, but since there's not much about that on the internet, at least not easy to find, maybe you can write it up, after you experiment with it :).

Comment: haha. Sure....... I don’t think enough people actually care about javascriptcore

Comment: Actually, because JavaScriptCore is part of WebKit, it's used by multiple browsers. It's also used by https://webkitgtk.org/ which in turn is used by multiple Gnome applications. I'm guessing that there are more people that care about JavaScriptCore than there are that care about using it from objective-c ;).

Comment: @ahwayakchih Maybe. Thats the problem.